# Automator Applescript - How to click the second checkbox

Tags: applescript, automator

I recorded a workflow with Automator. And I got the following code:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    -- Cliquez sur la case à cocher Selected features only.
    delay 1.051853
    set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
    set uiScript to "click checkbox \"Selected features only\" of group 1 of splitter group 1 of window \"Difference\" of application process \"QGIS 3\""
    my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
    return input
end run
```

How do I choose the exactly second checkbox (not the first item)?

[image: click the second checkbox, not the first one]

Comment: What do you get when you record clicking the second checkbox?  What is the posted script a recording of?

Comment: I've got the code above.

Comment: When you click the first item (whatever that is) and then the second checkbox, the UI elements are the same?

Comment: Exactly. I've got the same code repeated two times.

When I run the script, Automator just selects then deselects the first item.

Comment: If they are both in the same container, then using the title may just be getting the first one that matches.  Try getting the UI elements of that group 1 of splitter group 1 to see if both checkboxes are in there, or just try something like `checkbox 2` instead of the title.

Comment: I don't know how to get the UI elements of group 1. I just try number and: `click checkbox 3 of group 1` did the job. Thanks a lot @red_menace

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach, is to first get a list of your window's UI elements with the Apple provided Accessibility Inspector or directly in the Script Editor.

If you were to use the Script Editor, here's an example of how to find your checkboxes' names:

```
activate application "QGIS 3"

tell application "System Events" to tell process "QGIS 3"
    set frontmost to true
    set elements to (entire contents of window 1 as list)
    return elements
end tell
```

Your elements list, among which you'd hopefully find your second button name, will be output to the bottom Result pane.

Comment: You can also get UI elements by using Automator’s **Watch Me Do** action, which appears to be where the OP got the posted script.

Comment: That's what I supposed he did, but it seems the Automator is not accurate enough to distinguish between the checkboxes, thus the advice to try through the Script Editor or the Accessibility Inspector.

Comment: The script runs successfully, but I got nothing in Result pane